# No internet in terminal but can access it via browser

Tags: networking, updates, internet, gnome-terminal

To update or to install anything I tried it via terminal but the terminal gets stuck at 0% but I can still use the internet via browser. Cannot even install apps via AppCenter.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? Search in the configuration of your browser if there is a proxy server set.

Comment: Which Release are you using? What does your sources list say? MAKE and MODEL of computer OR basic specs.

Comment: I am not using any proxy servers and using Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki and my laptop is Lenovo Ideapad 320 with 8GB RAM .